# How can I make this code run in parallel ? For loop

Tags: r, furrr

I am trying to run this simple for loop as a parallel process as it requires lots of compute power. Any thoughts?

```
##Load files and libraries---
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)
library(insight)
library(MASS)
library(mfx)
library(furrr)

for (i in 1:16) {
      nested_inter$model[[i]]<- nb_thesis_inter(df= nested_nb$data[[i]], mdl= nested_nb$model[[i]])
      print (paste("Finished model ", i, "out of 16"))
    }

  #nested_inter<- nested_inter %>% 
  #  mutate(model= future_map2(.x= data, .y=model, .f = nb_thesis_inter))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My go to is the `future.apply` package.

```r
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession)

nested_inter$model = future_Map(nb_thesis_inter,
                                nested_nb$data,
                                nested_nb$model)
```

Two things to note.

1. `plan(multisession)` allows Windows to be used in parallel. See `?plan` for all options.
2. I did not install all of the packages because the example was not reproducible. The `future_Map` call may need to be changed to `future_map(function (x, y) nb_thesis_inter(df = x, mdl = y), ...)` depending on the default argument order of `nb_thesis_inter`.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's running and working.. How can I get benchmarks on the runtime or set different parameters for it? I want to compare to the for loop

Comment: ```system.time()```? I also like ```bench::mark()```. As far as more parameters, ```Map``` is ```Map(function(x, y) {your_function}, x_arg, y_arg)``` where we can keep adding more arguments if we want (e.g., we can have ```z_arg``` which would pass another argument to our function). In this example we already had a function ```nb_thesis_inter``` so we didn't have to create a new function within the ```Map``` call.

Comment: Oh. This is embarrassing - I'm not actually that good at this package!  I think ```?plan``` which then links to various strategies is good. For example ```?multisession``` which Ied me to try ```plan(multisession, workers = 4L)``` which worked.

Comment: Thanks! I will try to post it in another thread. Right now this code seems right and not working :-) 

bnch_future<-bench::mark(
nested_inter$model2 = future_Map(nb_thesis_inter,
                                nested_nb$data,
                                nested_nb$model))

Answer (score 0):

you could use `pmap`:

```
nested_nb %>% furrr::future_pmap(function(...){
  row <- list(...)
  nb_thesis_inter(df = row$data, mdl= row$model)
})
```